# When should I use decltype(expression)?

Tags: c++, decltype

I understand why do we need `decltype(auto)` and it's difference from `auto` , but I can't get why and when  I should/need to use `decltype(expression)`. In all examples on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) I can just use decltype(auto), I checked it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `void foo(int i) { for (decltype(i) j = 0; j < i; ++j) ... }`

Comment: @Evg make that an answer

Answer (score 3):

> but I can't get why and when I should/need to use `decltype(expression)`

In C++11 you can use trailing return types but not auto-deduced return types. E.g.:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u) { return t + u; }
```

C++14 equivalent is:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
decltype(auto) add(T t, U u) { return t + u; }
```

---

Another use is SFINAE, e.g. detecting existence of a member function with a specific name:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
auto test_has_f(T* p) -> decltype(static_cast<void>(p->f()), std::true_type{}); // Cast to void to avoid user-defined operator,(), if any.

std::false_type test_has_f(void*);

template<class T>
using HasF = decltype(test_has_f(static_cast<T*>(0)));

struct A {};
struct B { void f(); };

int main() {
    std::cout << HasF<A>::value << '\n'; // Outputs 0.
    std::cout << HasF<B>::value << '\n'; // Outputs 1.
}
```

Comment: It's a pity, but I can't really understand what your second code example is doing.. Went to read about SFINAE

Comment: @DoehJohn It detects whether a class has a member function named `f` at compile time, see the 2 lines of usage in `main`.

Comment: I understand the usage, you wrote you own traits,  but didn't quite understand how it works under the hood

Comment: @DoehJohn https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

Answer (score 3):

The simplest example I could come up with is this:

```
void foo(int i) {
    for (decltype(i) j = 0; j < i; ++j) 
        ...
}
```

Here, the index `j` automatically has the same type as the upper bound `i`.

An alternative example is provided by a lambda expression:

```
[](auto i) {
    for (decltype(i) j = 0; j < i; ++j) 
        ...    
}
```

Comment: If you can walk back to front then you can also do `for(auto j = i; j--;)`.

Comment: but I can use decltype(auto) instead of decltype(i)

Comment: @DoehJohn In this particular example, you can. But the idea is that `int` can be any type, possibly unknown like in a generic lambda.

Comment: @Evg yes, but 
[](auto i) {
    for (decltype(auto) j = 0; j < i; ++j) 
        ...    
}

works

Comment: @DoehJohn, `j` will always have type `int`, independent of type of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to declare a type which is related to another type but want to keep it agnostic:

```
struct foo
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    decltype(data)::iterator it;
};
```

Comment: An actual *expression* to deduce from? There is a type here.

Comment: @user253751 `data` is an expression

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Not one you can deduce from

Comment: @user253751 Ah, didn't see the first revision. 